# Angular HTTP Proxy to call secured backend

Tags: angular, http, proxy, authorization, froala

I'm using Froala HTML Editor in my app, and I want the attachments to be posted on my backend server which is secured (every request must have the Authorization header set or have the access_token URL param).

Although there is a requestHeaders param in the Froala editor, the problem is that it makes a POST request to the backend to post the attachment, and when the request is complete it puts the URL of the attachment in the src attribute of the img or as href in the link, which results in a GET request, which in my case should be also secured.

I did a research on that, and all that I have found is to use Angular Pipe, but for that I need Angular specific attribute in square brackets on the img element, which should be parsed by Angular, but I have no access to do that. Other solutions that I have found is to use interceptors, but they intercept only the calls made by the @angular/http component.

So I got the idea to implement a controller method on the Frontend (probably in Angular) which intercepts the HTTP GET requests made to a certain URL, like: http://localhost:4200/#/attachments/{id} or http://localhost:4200/#/attachments?id={id} and if there is a request made to this endpoint, than the controller method that I have mentioned before intercepts the call, builds up a backend URL, sets the Authorization header, makes the actual request, and forwards the response to the frontend. But I didn't find out until now how can I implement such a controller method in Angular. I'm using Angular 5.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is to use [a Bearer Token](https://blog.strongbrew.io/safe-image-requests-in-angular/) and insert it in the [image.uploaded callback](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/issues/2112#issuecomment-321190805).

Comment: The problem with this is that the bearer token changes when the user logs in again and we store the content of the editor in the DB. So when the user comes back and loads the data from the DB there will be a lot of img elements with incorrect access token.

Comment: You'd have to add the access token each time the HTML is inserted again in the editor. Unfortunately, there is no simple straightforward way for doing it.

Comment: But how? Parsing the string that comes from the DB? It would be too complicated and would take a lot of resources. Somebody recommended me to use MutationObserver, this still sounds weird.

Comment: You could do something like described here: http://blog.jsgoupil.com/request-image-files-with-angular-2-and-an-bearer-access-token/#disqus_thread. All you should take care is that you're outputting the editor content with the [src] on it, however, this could be easily made in the html.get event with a RegEx.

Comment: This still will fail, because for example I add an image with the [src] attribute on it (it threw me an error, I tried it already - because square brackets are not valid HTML, but let’s say I put it somehow there) and I save the content in the DB. The user then opens the page where the content is shown inside a div element with innerHTML Angular tag, the problem here is that the src from the square brackets will be parsed, and therefore lost, so when the user pushes the Edit button and the content will be loaded into the editor, I guess I will lose the Angular binding from the [src] tag.

Comment: Instead of putting the [src], you could add a data-src attribute on the image and then add [src] attribute to the image based on data-src just before rendering it.

Comment: I’m rendering a string which comes from the DB, so it is a bit hard to add the [src] attribute, and if I could do such a thing I would better add the access token than. But if I manage somehow to add the [src] attribute in the uploaded event of the editor than I will create blobs in the pipe and link them to the img element.

Comment: Adding [src] as an attribute is not possible as the browsers do not allow that. The best approach would be to add data-src as an attribute and just before displaying the string which you get from DB, convert data-src over to [src] using a regular expression.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion but it seems that [src] is not binded when inserting the content through [innerHTML]